# JBehave reuse steps from dependent projects

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jbehave

I have two java maven projects `xxx-test` and `yyy-test`.

Both have a dependency on `test-util`.

I have a common `Then` step method which I want to place in `test-util` so `xxx-test` and `yyy-test` can both use it. In other words, I want for `xxx-test` to have a story with a `Then` step that is mapped to a method from `test-util`.

Can this be possible? When I try to do this, those `Then` steps get `PENDING` status and are not executed.

Here is what JBehave documentation says to check for troubleshooting:

- the methods are public
- the method annotations @Given/@When/@Then
  correspond to the keyword used in the step the pattern specified in
- the annotation is matching the step, using place holders of the
  parameters

All of bullets hold. So I don't even know what else to do.

**UPDATE:**
I also tried to add the dependency to `maven-failsafe-plugin` that runs integration tests. I mean the `dependenciesToScan` parameter. I didn't help. As well as `dependencies` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the test-util class in your test runner code.  This method you are describing is not only possible, it's recommended.  All re-usable steps should be placed in a common class so that you can avoid "duplicate step" by repeating the step in both of the other tests.  For one setting that I have, I have only two steps files, one which contains all the steps needed to create a "group" and the other that has all the steps required to "enroll" options in the created groups.  I then have about 12 different stories that all use mostly the same steps, with only a few exceptions, but those exceptions are also included in the two steps files.  This way, all the stories can start with "Given I am logged in as..." and not throw a warning like it would if you were to keep all steps only in the steps file that corresponds by name to the story file.

Hope I've not confused you further.

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood the issue. test-util is not a class- it is a separate module. I want to have a 'then' method there that can be called from other modules so that I can reuse it in different modules. If I place it in a class in same module, it works fine. When I try to put it to a separate module, JBehave cannot find it.

Comment: I don't know if it's standard, but our JBehave was originally only loading the corresponding .java files for every .story file it found/processed.  I modified the code such that it instead loads all classes contained in the \src\test\steps folder we have with the sole exception being the testrunner itself.  If the test-util module is located in the same folder, it could be simply included in the list of steps that it loads prior to the suite run.  The code is fairly short, but it might not apply to your framework.  I can post it if you'd like.